# How do I factor equations involving $e^x$?

Tags: calculus, factoring, exponential-function

I was reviewing some of my notes from Calculus 1 so that I can prepare for Calculus 2 this fall, and I ran into one problem where I don't understand how the factoring works.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{1/x}+e^{-1/x}}{e^{1/x}-e^{-1/x}}$$

Then substituting... $$u = \frac {1}{x}$$

I know what the answer to this question is, but this step in the solution manual confused me:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^u(1+e^{-2u})}{e^u(1-e^{-2u})}$$

My brain is still getting prepared to get back into doing math regularly after the summer vacation, but I'm hitting a serious wall trying to understand how this expression can be factored this way.

Any help in understanding this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: First there isn't any $n$ in the expression after the lim symbol. But it also looks like you miscopied something from the solution manual. I think the top factor should be $(1+e^{-2u})$. That way when "multiplied out" the top becomes $e^u+e^{-u}$ as it should to match.

Comment: @coffeemath good catch!  Both typos.  I will fix now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: If $u=1/x$ then $e^u(1+e^{-2u})=e^u+e^{-u}=e^\frac1x+e^{-\frac1x}$ which now matches the top of your expression. Similarly $e^u(1-e^{2u})$ matches the bottom of the expression. In the $u$ version the two $e^u$ factors cancel, and the expression becomes
$$\frac{1+e^{-2/x}}{1-e^{-2/x}}.$$
This looks like, as $x \to \infty$, then $-2/x \to 0$ so that the exponential terms go to 1 and it diverges.

Comment: Actually, it does not since $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+e^{-\frac{2}{x}}) = 2 \neq 0$

Comment: @DoctorDan Correct comment. So it diverges...

Answer (score 1):

if you have substituted u = 1/x then your limit is now u → 0 and e<sup>-2u</sup> → 1.  The top term → 2 and the bottom term to -∞.  So yes it diverges.  Coffeemath said the same thing, but I want to point out to be careful that when you change variables you also must change the limits accordingly.